# Finding the solution of a summation of exponentials

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve numerically this equation in Python (numpy/scipy, everything is available)

[image]

In this formula *K* is a constant, *f* and *g* are two terms those depends on the E counter (this is a discrete representation of an integral) where *x* is the variable I'm looking for.

As an example, with *E* being 3 terms that'd be:

[image]

also *f(E)* and *g(E)* are known.

I read about using "fsolve" from numpy, although I can't understand how to automatically generate a function that's a summation of terms. I may do it manually but being 50 terms that'd take a while, also I'd love to learn something new.

Comment: What is E that you are summing over? What is F? What is G? What is x? What is K? Please be more specific.

Comment: Edited to be a bit more specific. The problem I find is there are *50* terms I've to add manually.

Comment: Have you considered using a `for` or `while` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) where the function is constructed using [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

np.random.seed(123)

f = np.random.uniform(size=50)
g = np.random.uniform(size=f.size)
K = np.sum(f * np.exp(-g*np.pi))

def func(x, f, g, K):
    return np.sum(f * np.exp(-g*x), axis=0) - K

# The argument to the function is an array itself,
# so we need to introduce extra dimensions for f, g.
res = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, x0=1, args=(f[:, None], g[:, None], K))
```

Note that for your specific function you can also assist the algorithm by providing the derivative of the function:

```
def derivative(x, f, g, K):
    return np.sum(-g*f * np.exp(-g*x), axis=0)

res = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, fprime=derivative,
                            x0=1, args=(f[:, None], g[:, None], K))
```

## Finding multiple roots

You can vectorize the procedure in a sense that the function accepts N inputs (for example for each of the rows) and produces N outputs (again one for each row). Hence the inputs and outputs are independent of each other and the corresponding jacobian is a diagonal matrix. Here's some sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

np.random.seed(123)

image = np.random.uniform(size=(4000, 3000, 2))
f, g = image[:, :, 0], image[:, :, 1]
x_original = np.random.uniform(size=image.shape[0])  # Compute for each of the rows.
K = np.sum(f * np.exp(-g * x_original[:, None]), axis=1)

def func(x, f, g, K):
    return np.sum(f * np.exp(-g*x[:, None]), axis=1) - K

def derivative(x, f, g, K):
    return np.diag(np.sum(-g*f * np.exp(-g*x[:, None]), axis=1))

res = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, fprime=derivative,
                            x0=0.5*np.ones(x_original.shape), args=(f, g, K))
assert np.allclose(res, x_original)
```

Comment: I've been trying this method on my script but it's quite slow since I'd have to do that for a 4000x3000ish image (and try to solve each row and column in a for.).
would there be a quicker way to do it?

Comment: @DavideBarbieri You can vectorize the procedure and hand the loop over to Numpy. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: the problem is that both f and g are two vectors of 57 (attenuation coefficients) and those are all the same for the whole image while `x` is the matrix I'm looking at.

Comment: @DavideBarbieri You mean you want to find a solution for each of the image's pixels (i.e. `4,000 x 3,000 = 12,000,000` equations)? In that case you can use the original code from above and swap `fsolve` with `root(method='diagbroyden')`. Computing a full jacobian (which is diagonal anyway) is not feasible and the `diagbroyden` solver takes that into account. However you cannot inject your custom jacobian via `jac`, it'll be ignored. I feel there should be a method that operates on exact diagonal jacobian but as of now I couldn't find one. I think that's worth a separate question.

Comment: @DavideBarbieri Otherwise you could process the image in chunks for which the above 2nd method won't run out of memory but since it uses a full jacobian it's not really efficient. I tried using `scipy.sparse` diagonal matrices but the algorithm didn't like them (reports shape mismatch though there is actually none).

Comment: I have this image of 4000x3000 pixel I have to calculate that formula on, each pixel has to be analyzed this way (there should be a continuity between pixels but that'd be a next step). The `f` and `g` are just an array of constants those have to be multiplied in order to get the results, but those have nothing to do with the image.
For this reason the for was my idea of going: every pixel is not related to the other so I can send in different equation 4000*3000 times, I was thinking if there was a way to make it quicker since 4000*3000 iterations in a for took a long time.