# Using scipy.fsolve on a matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, numeric, numerical-methods

Following the help I was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258368/finding-the-solution-of-a-summation-of-exponentials/54259469#54259469) I've been trying to implement it in my script but I'm failing at running it smartly.

I need to use this algorithm for each pixel of a 4072x3080 image, this takes around 1h30 for the whole process, so I tried to force it somehow but I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-99c1f41dbba7> in <module>()
----> 1 res = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, x0=np.ones((K.shape[0], K.shape[1])), args=(f[:,None], g[:,None], K))

/*/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in fsolve(func, x0, args, fprime, full_output, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    146                'diag': diag}
    147 
--> 148     res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
    149     if full_output:
    150         x = res['x']

/*/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)
    212     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    213         args = (args,)
--> 214     shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
    215     if epsfcn is None:
    216         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

/*/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     25 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     26                 output_shape=None):
---> 27     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     28     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     29         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

<ipython-input-7-911c817cb57d> in func(x, f, g, K)
      1 def func(x, f, g, K):
----> 2     return np.sum(f * np.exp(-g*x), axis=0) - K
      3 
      4 
      5 def derivative(x, f, g, K):

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13551616,) (4072,3328)
```

This is the code I've been trying:

```
def func(x, f, g, K):
    return np.sum(f * np.exp(-g*x), axis=0) - K


def derivative(x, f, g, K):
    return np.sum(-g*f * np.exp(-g*x), axis=0)
```

+

```
res = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, x0=np.ones((K.shape[0], K.shape[1])), args=(f[:,None], g[:,None], K))
```

`f` and `g` are both `(47,)` arrays, where `K` is a `(4072, 3328)` image

Elseway the slow process goes down this way: (but this one fails with derivative anyhow.

```
res = np.ones((mbn.shape[0],mbn.shape[1]))
for i_x in range(0,mbn.shape[0]):
    if i_x%10 == 0:
        print i_x/4070 
    for i_y in range(0,mbn.shape[1]):
        res[i_x,i_y] = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, x0=1, args=(f[:], g[:], K[i_x,i_y]) )
```

This would be the error if I try to use the slow method with the derivate

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ValueError: object of too small depth for desired array

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-3587dcccfd93> in <module>()
      4         print i_x/4070
      5     for i_y in range(0,mbn.shape[1]):
----> 6         res[i_x,i_y] = scipy.optimize.fsolve(func, fprime=derivative, x0=1, args=(f[:], g[:], K[i_x,i_y]) )

/*/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in fsolve(func, x0, args, fprime, full_output, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    146                'diag': diag}
    147 
--> 148     res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
    149     if full_output:
    150         x = res['x']

/*/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.pyc in _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac, col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, band, eps, factor, diag, **unknown_options)
    232         with _MINPACK_LOCK:
    233             retval = _minpack._hybrj(func, Dfun, x0, args, 1,
--> 234                                      col_deriv, xtol, maxfev, factor, diag)
    235 
    236     x, status = retval[0], retval[-1]

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Comment: How are `f`, `g` and `K` defined? Runnable code with random data would be helpful.

Comment: `f` and `g` are both `(47,)` arrays, where `K` is a `(4072, 3328)` image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `func` in [`optimize.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) can accept a 1-dimensional vector, but not 2-dimensional arrays.
So even though `K` and `x` are 2-dimensional, for this calculation it behooves us to reshape them as 1D arrays.

```
Kshape = K.shape
K = K.ravel()
```

Then after calling `optimize.fsolve`, you can reshape the result to be once again 2D:

```
res = optimize.fsolve(func, x0=np.ones(K.shape).ravel(), args=(f, g, K))
res = res.reshape(Kshape)
```

---

You can then avoid the double for-loops by writting the computation this way:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize

np.random.seed(123)

def func(x, f, g, K):
    return np.sum(f * np.exp(-g*x[:, None]), axis=-1) - K


def derivative(x, f, g, K):
    return np.sum(-g*f * np.exp(-g*x[:, None]), axis=-1)


f = np.random.uniform(size=(47,))
g = np.random.uniform(size=f.shape)
K = np.random.uniform(size=(4072,3080))
Kshape = K.shape
K = K.ravel()

res = optimize.fsolve(func, x0=np.ones(K.shape).ravel(), args=(f, g, K))
res = res.reshape(Kshape)
print(res)
```

Notice that `g*x[:, None]` uses [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to generate a 2D array of shape `(4072*3080, 47)`. The 2D array `f * np.exp(-g*x[:, None])`,
which is also of shape `(4072*3080, 47)`, is then summed over the last axis (i.e. `axis=-1`).
This leaves a 1D array of shape `(4072*3080,)`. `fsolve` solves for `x` and returns a 1D array of shape `(4072*3080,)`.

`res = res.reshape(Kshape)` reshapes the solution to have shape `(4072, 3080)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorize the problem by creating a function that takes N inputs and N outputs where N is the number of pixels. This involves flattening the input image and treating it as a 1D array. In this setup the inputs are independent from the outputs and hence the jacobian is diagonal. Because `fsolve` computes a full approximation of the jacobian you'll eventually run out of memory (`MemoryError`). Instead you can use [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) with `method='diagbroyden'` which uses an approximation by only tracking the diagonal jacobian:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def func(x, f, g, K):
    return np.sum(f * np.exp(-g*x[:, None]), axis=1) - K

np.random.seed(123)

f = np.random.uniform(size=(47,))
g = np.random.uniform(size=f.shape)
img = np.random.uniform(size=(4072, 3328)).ravel()
K = func(img, f, g, 0)

res = optimize.root(func, method='diagbroyden', x0=0.5*np.ones(img.size), args=(f, g, K))
print('Success:', res.success)
print('Message:', res.message)
assert np.allclose(img, res.x)
```

With this method however you cannot take advantage of the analytic derivative that can be computed for your specific function.

Comment: @LutzL I am not sure what you mean by that but in any case storing the diagonal matrix requires only O(n) memory (as opposed to O(n^2) for the full matrix). Since the diagonal Broyden approximation stores a diagonal approximation of the Jacobian and uses diagonal updates to it, it has O(n) complexity. The [`diagbroyden` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.diagbroyden.html) state the following: *"The Jacobian approximation is derived from previous iterations, by retaining only the diagonal of Broyden matrices."*.

Comment: Ok, I've read that page before but missed this sentence and its meaning in the first reading. Still, it seems wastefull to attack a collection of non-coupled scalar equations  with a method for (weakly) coupled equations.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad idea to transform the solution of `n` scalar root-finding problems into a vectorized `n`-dimensional root finding problem. The singular decisions that the scalar solver makes are generally not uniform over all input variants, and any general solver of systems will attempt to compute or approximate the Jacobian. While we know that it is diagonal it this setting, it might be complicated to communicate this to the solver. Additionally, as said before, decisions for step sizes, line searches etc. when taken uniformly for the vectorized problem are almost guaranteed to be sub-optimal for every single scalar problem.

The best strategy is to reduce the amount of scalar problems to solve, or to at least use the one-dimensional nature to get a good approximation of the inverse function that then only requires very few iterations to polish the solution.

#### case of small amount of integer values in K

You want to call a complicated function (iterative inversion) a large number of times on inputs that are closely related, may even take only a limited number of values.

A first idea for faster calculation is to first determine the range of the values of `K`, compute the value of `x` for each of the actually present values and then distribute these values back over the image array. For instance, if `K` only takes integer values from `0` to `255`, then producing an array `x_vals` where `func(x_vals[k],f,g,0)=k` allows to give the resulting array as `x_vals[K]` a la

```
x_vals = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4])
K = np.array([[1,2],[0,2],[3,3]]);
x=x_vals[K]; print x
```

---

```
array([[ 0.2,  0.3],
       [ 0.1,  0.3],
       [ 0.4,  0.4]])
```

---

#### case of a relatively small range of non-integer values in K

If `K` contains a larger amount of (non-integer) values in some relatively (to the values in `f`) small range, it may still provide a large improvement to compute the solutions for some sampling `K_samples = np.linspace(np.amin(K), np.amax(K), 256)` so that func(x_samples[k],f,g,0)=K_samples[k])`

Then a *solution* or at least a *very good approximation* for further iterative refinement is obtained using interpolation

```
x = np.interp(K, K_samples, x_samples)
```

#### using forward evaluation of func

If the vectors `f` and `g` are both positive-valued, then the sum of exponentials is a monotonically falling function, whose inverse can be given by a simple look-up table and linear interpolation of it.  For the values of the sum-of-exponentials function one gets

```
sum(f)*exp(-max(g)*x) <= K <= sum(f)*exp(-min(g)*x)
```

so that one can compute a range for `x` as

```
- log(max(K)/sum(f)) / max(g)  <=  x  <=  - log(min(K)/sum(f)) / min(g)
```

Using these upper and lower bounds to produce an array `x_samples` one gets the corresponding `K_samples` by forward evaluation of `func`. Linear interpolation to get an approximation of the inverse function proceeds as above.